# Is it possible to capture a 433MHz RF signal using the PC bluetooth?

Tags: rf, bluetooth, transceiver

I'm student working on a project at my university where I have to transmit a signal that I'm generating with a micro controller using a SmartALPHA RF Transceiver with a 433MHz signal. I have to receive this data and use it to plot a graph on the PC. Is it possible to capture this signal using the bluetooth from the computer? The original project used another SmartALPHA to receive it and transfer to the computer by serial port, but my professor modified it and asked for me to try doing it using only one.

Comment: AFAIK, no. Bluetooth devices are not 433MHz, and cannot function as general purpose RF receivers.

Comment: Question is why did your Professor ask for that? Did they explain at all aside from "just use one?"

Comment: Short answer, no. Longer answer, your professor messed up and wants you to clean up after him. Bluetooth is 2.4GHz, any semi decent design will include bandpass filters on the antenna, blocking any other frequency.

Comment: May be he was talking about transreciever?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get it at the time that it was going to be a problem, because I didn't know what band a BT worked and I was more focused on implementing the signal transmission. I guess I'll have to talk to him and discuss some modifications on this project. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

One reason is getting the whip antenna for the bluetooth to accept such a "low frequency" signal requires hardware modification and re-tuning of the reception circuitry, since BT is 2.4GHz.

Another reason, even if you'd get the chip to accept the lower centre band frequency is that the encoding scheme and signalling bands on both protocols are vastly different, so it would make no sense at all to the chip that is hard-wired for BT.